# Transact-SQL - Select Value and add custom String If value is too long

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement, select, string-length

I've put together a long statement that among other things selects different product names from a table. In my application, I want to limit the length of this name to 100 characters. So far, I've realized this by using LEFT(product_name, 100) within my query. However, I would like to add a '...' to the value in case the name is actually longer than 100 characters so the user knows that the actual value is a little bit longer than what he sees.

So if I only had 2 products in my database:

```
1: 'Awesome product'
2: 'Another totally awsome product that will make your life a lot better if you buy it because it is really awesome in many ways.'
```

The result should look like this:

```
1: 'Awesome product'
2: 'Another totally awsome product that will make your life a lot better if you buy it because it is rea...'
```

How can I do this with a simple SELECT query? My first instinct was to try something with IF:

```
SELECT LEFT(product_name, 100) + (IF LEN(product_name > 100) '...')
```

but that just gives me an error.

Comment: If truncating the string on any character good enough or would you want to break it at the nearest whole word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
(case when len(product_name) <= 100 then product_name
      else left(product_name, 97) + '...'
 end) as new_product_name
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just offering this as something you could use if you wanted a "clean" break, ie without chopping a word in half:

```
declare @string varchar(200)='Another totally awsome product that will make your life a lot better if you buy it because it is really awesome in many ways.', @len tinyint=100
select
case when len(@string)>@len 
    then Stuff(@string,@len+1-CharIndex(' ', (Reverse(Left(@string,@len)))),200,'...')
else @string end
```